# UK plab2 visa reapplication

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

[image]

I am a Nigerian doctor working in Saudi Arabia. I am married with 2 children but my family resides in Nigeria. I was denied a plab 2 visa recently (see picture) and I am planning to reapply. I have also been denied 2 years ago for a visit visa due to lack of funds/fund parking.
What are changes I could make to improve my chances? 
By changes I mean:

**1** Should I reduce my proposed length of stay to 3 days? This I already plan to do.

**2** The only evidence that I have booked for this exam is the confirmation email usually sent after paying. How do I go about getting it certified like the ECO hinted?
Should I include other things like a receipt generated from the GMC website? Also include all the email communication I have had with the GMC?

**3** I stated I wanted to familiarize myself with the UK healthcare system. This was interpreted by the ECO to mean I wanted to do a clinical attachment. Should I explain this in my cover letter, on the application website or totally ignore it?

**4** I applied for a PLAB visa. However I was assessed under the clinical attachment category. Should I point it out or keep quiet?

**5** This last application was in Nigeria during my leave, now I plan to apply in Saudi Arabia. Does this affect my outcome positively or otherwise?

Comment: In addition to any individual advice, you should read the new canonical question [I have been denied a visa several times in a row. How does one deal with such serial refusals?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99216/19560)