# US Tourist Visa refusal under 214

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

So my boyfriend was refused his tourist visa to the US today as he allegedly doesn't have strong enough ties. They asked him if he had kids (no, he's only 26 afterall), where he lives and read his letter of employment. That's pretty much it. The lady said he would only get a visa if his situation changes considerably.

So he's obviously going to reapply with more documents. Here's the thing: he does not own or rent property (stays with his dad and grandparents), doesn't have a spouse or kids (again, he's 26 I don't know how they can expect that really).

So what else can he use to demonstrate strong ties? We were thinking cell phone contract, obviously the employment stuff that was presented, possibly taking out an investment? His car is in his name but is paid off. We were thinking maybe if he enrolls in a course next year that should prove that he needs to come back.

He also helps look after his wheelchair bound grandmother and contributes financially to the household. He has two dogs that are basically his kids whom he is solely responsible for.

I suppose the only considerable change would be one of property and/or marriage. We are in a long term relationship so I suppose its not totally out of the question. Seeing as I don't want to get married at all I would really not like to just for a holiday haha

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** after the initial visa refusal he went to see a visa specialist and reapplied. He just took a lot more documentation with him than the first one, no other changes and he was given his visa :)

Comment: More documents are not going to change the underlying reason he was refused, lack of ties. More is not necessarily better. He's heading for another quick refusal. `The lady said he would only get a visa if his situation changes considerably.` Nothing has changed nor will change considerably in the short to medium term for the average 26 year old.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99216/58919 for more information on how to handle this situation.

Comment: You seem to be hung up on the question of his not having children.  Millions of childless people visit the US every year; nobody's "expecting" him to have kids.  But a 26-year-old with children is perhaps more likely to be strongly tied to his place of residence than one without.  There's nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: You should really read the question and especially answers that @JacobHorbulyk linked. The first bullet point under "*What can I do to improve my odds in the future? How can I break the pattern?*" in [the accepted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/99250/51958) seems especially pertinent to your situation.

Comment: No university instruction?, no real estate ownership, no significant savings, low paid job, working age, no kids, RSA? - problematic country....seems pretty standard the refusal, I am afraid. I visited the USA under a Portuguese passport around that age, however was "randomly selected" and had a talk with the FBI upon arrival. I only had a suit in my suitcase, three shirts and some underwear, told them was there for a computer conference, they let me go. As he is already in their list, I doubt that even marrying and using a PT passport he will be able to make it in the near future.

Comment: Also a relevant question... whose CC paid for the flight? His or yours?

Comment: He has university instruction. He studied veternary sciences for 2 years before ultimately changing and studying and qualifying in his current feild. He has been employed by his current employer since 2013. He has a decent paying job. He has significant savings and had proof of his bank accounts etc. Although I don't think they looked at that. He has a car in his name but its paid off. He doesn't like opening shop accounts etc because he doesn't like to owe money. He likes to pay with what he has. He helps financially at home. My dad bought the tickets for the group and has been paid back.

Comment: Funnily enough my cousin works for the FBI, seriously considering asking her to write a letter for him

Comment: @RoxC Your dad buying the tickets is one of the red flags. It does not matter wether he is being paid back. It ought to be him paying.

Comment: He didn't present the tickets nor was he asked so it couldn't possibly be a red flag

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best option would be a **stable, well-paid** job. Something where he makes so much that it would not be *rational* for him to overstay instead of returning home to resume his job.

Comment: Seems like the job isn't enough (we provided certificate of employment, leave granted and pay slips). We're at the point now of does he try again with further info as I mentioned above or not waste the cash. Our trip is planned and flights are booked (they are refundable at least) so he would like to try again

Comment: @RoxC, I don't know how much he earns (and you shouldn't tell strangers on the net such details), but is it close to the average salary in the US? Or even the average salary for people of his age?

Comment: @o.m. If the user tags hold any clues, and coupled with her question, the average salary for his age is probably less than 10k-15k USD per year for an office job, and lower for menial jobs.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, there are many countries where the average salary for a middle-aged professional is lower than that. People like that might be seen as potential illegal immigrants.

Comment: Yeah he earns I would say average just above for RSA. He's a landscape designer so I'm not sure what that's like in the US in terms of earnings.

Comment: My aunt luckily works in the travel industry and is going to help us with everything he could possibly take to prove strong ties to the country. Also with the whole marriage thing, its not something either of us wants in our lives. We don't want kids at all either. So these are things that aren't likely to change for either of us. We're just going to arm with more information than he had.