# Vietnamese wife refused visit visa for 3rd time!

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, vietnam

[Any advice is greatly appreciated, this has been an absolute nightmare]

My wife and I have been married for 3 years, known each other for 6. We're both still in our 20s. We have a 5-month old daughter, a business here in Vietnam and property. Both have never set foot in the UK and it's causing my ageing family a lot of grief.

Our daughter's Right of Abode was accepted. However, my wife's third family visit visa was refused. We suspect the ECO gave poor consideration to the most recent application and mainly focused on the previous two refusals from 2015 and 2016.

In the first paragraph, the ECO specifies we intended to visit the UK for 1 month and 2 weeks (as indicated on a previous application.) This was false. On our most recent application we intended to travel for 3 weeks.

In the second paragraph, the ECO mentioned my wife's previous employment from 2015, which is totally irrelevant today. We had provided her certificate of business ownership, tax paid, signed customer receipts, invoices, bank statements, and pictures. How can my wife most effectively demonstrate she is the owner of a business and her monthly income?

In the third paragraph the ECO specifies our evidence of finances (customer receipts and invoices) were not translated. They were. We had one template translation for a receipt voucher and one for an invoice voucher. Altogether, there are over 500 vouchers, which would be ridiculous to translate. Furthermore, the Visa Application Centre (VAC) does not allow us to scan anything that is not A4 size, nor allow us to send zip files via email (the law had changed 2 days prior on 11/06/2018 according to the VAC staff.) In this paragraph, the ECO also noted my wife's salary sheet could easily be fabricated. She is the owner of a private business, who else would issue her salary?

Lastly, despite being married since 2015, having a child together, as well as numerous pictures of our family, life, wedding, and business over 6 years, the ECO argued we did not appear to be in a genuine relationship. This one really hit home hard, so what might the ECO consider to be a genuine relationship?

So overall, how can my wife best show she has the funds and assets to return to? How can we show we're in a genuine relationship? Should we wait 2 years before applying again? Or would it make a difference if we tried a different visa?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please upload a redacted version of the refusal letter? This question currently contains your subjective assessment of the letter. I'm afraid without that you will only get guesses here.

Comment: Related: [I have been denied a visa several times in a row. How does one deal with such serial refusals?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se)

Comment: Ask a UK friend to look your application with critical eyes. Probably you assume too much (so you leave some important details). You can also increase changes by traveling on other countries (without getting banned).

Comment: It is possible to lodge a complaint if you feel that evidence has been ignored/inaccurate statements have been made.  It won't get you a visa, but it may get you a refunded of fees/a free "another try"

Comment: Definitely upload a scanned image of the most recent refusal letter. If possible, also upload images of the _previous_ refusal letters.

Comment: Is your property rented? How long has your business been established for and is it profitable? Do you have business premises or is it run online? Who will run it for you while you are away? It’s possible the ECO thinks your family’s ties in Vietnam are intangible.