# Germany Visiting Friends Visa Remonstrance Denied

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, germany, schengen-visas

I am Indian married woman working in big textile company as Confirmed employment.
I applied for Germany visa for 90 days to visit friends but was rejected stating reason that purpose not reliable then I again reapply with changed cover letter  but  again rejected with reason of inadequate insurance and reason means leaving Schengen area is ascertained then I file remonstrance.
They call me for interview and asking me for my husband assurence letter for caring my children for 90 days which I submitted immediately and after one month I got  letter answering my remonstrance stating they contact my employer but no response so, they doubt about employment. In addition to that, they finger on transaction and stating my funds came from Germany but actually my husband transfer that, funds to my account and for his ref. he  named it Germany but embassy people thought this came from Germany.

Third point they told 90 Days visa when you have two dependent children are unbelievable.
So my point is they contact my registered office which is closed so they can not contact my employer but fact is I submitted my ID card having my office address and Phone number then why not they contact to my office?
Why they refer my registered office number which printed on My employment leave letter? How they do not know that in bank statement never show country name?

When I submitted husband assurance letter then why they raise point of 90 days and my children?  If so then why asked me for assurance letter?
BTW, I submitted Formal obligation letter, light ticket, insurance. My company salary slips appointment letter, bank statement and car registration paper and children birth certificate.
Looking for advice.

Comment: I forgot mention but I have fresh passport means no travel history

Comment: Welcome, Shweta. While you've given a lot of information, it is not clear what you're asking and this site has a question and answer format. There are other  [questions that may explain what to consider](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216) such as the linked answer, and help you decide what to do.

Comment: this would be a lot easier to read if the big wall of text was broken up into paragraph-like segments

Comment: @MatthewBarclay, you would have been welcome to do it, but as you did not, I did the edit myself.

Answer (score 1):

The visa officials want to give visas to *genuine* tourists and business travelers, and deny visas to people trying to immigrate illegally. They decided that you do not look like the usual traveler:

- It is unusual that a parent with two children would want a 90-day visa without those kids.
- It is unusual that an employed person would want a 90-day visa.

If you had a formal *Verpflichtungserklärung* that can make a difference in some cases, but it seems that many problems were coming together.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reduce duration of travel for the first visa once you have visa next time you can ask for longer duration.
Also could you please share how to initiate remonstrance in India.

Comment: If your visa is refused, you receive a paper with instructions on how to initiate the remonstrance.