# UK visit visa refusal based on Finances

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I was recently refused a UK Standard visit visa For two reasons.

1.in the online application I answered the question do You have any income or savings? No!(Mistake no1) because I Had also stated I have £100 monthly exPenditure, of which what I meant was I get £100 In cash from my Mother for personal use.So the case worker siteD how I spend that if I have no income or savings.
So how do I rectify this in my re-application? On the income and saving do I state the £100 and explain in the cover letter who I get it from and it’s use?

2.I provided my bank statement with £2000. The money was withdrawn from my mother’s personal account and I then deposited the funds into mine. However when my mother requested for her bank statements, we don’t not thoroughly check them and it turned out that the dates on which the withdraws were made had been missing as the Banks statements given were just other random transactions(mistake no2). And so the origin of the funds came into question.

How best can I correct this in my re-application?

I figured, if I provide the correct and precise Bank statements that will show the amounts and date of the with draws, which will coincide with the amounts and dates of deposits made into mine, that would clarify the issue.

However am here to seek advise and any effective alternatives would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: I believe the application allows you to state who is actually paying for your expenses during your trip, which is common for young people depending on their parents, or partners staying at home and depending on the revenu of their partner. Don’t try to invent revenue you don’t have, but include your mother as the person paying for your trip. But note that you not having your own revenue may be bad for your application whatever happens, especially if you apply just by yourself (rather than making a trip with your family), as it reduces your ties to your home country and your incentive to return

Comment: I had done the same thing on my last visa application which was successful. I had got money from my mother and deposited it into mine. I don’t intend invent any revenue. How can I correct my errors in my next application?

Answer (score 3):

You made two significant errors in this application:

a) you provided inaccurate or incorrect bank statements;. Submitted bank statements should accurately reflect the actual status of the account(s). Inaccurate or inapplicable documents don't support your application, and encourage the examiner to disbelieve the rest of your statements and presentation.

b) You engaged in "funds parking," which in UKVI's view misrepresents the true state of your finances. This is disqualifying, and generates the same bad results as above. Read [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking). [This other question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se) about how to gather and present your information will be helpful as well.