# I was banned from UK for giving false information

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, nigerian-citizens, visa-bans

I am a Nigerian, I was banned from UK for 10 years 12 years ago for stating that I haven’t applied before and used a wrong date of birth in my previous passport. I lied because I was a teenager when I applied the first time and my passport and application was handled by an agent who made a mistake with my age.

My ban was over 2 years ago, please how do I go about my application. Thank you

Comment: I lied because I didn’t have the information of the passport the agent applied with as at that time

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to go to the UK?

Comment: @Hetty Have you got a good travel history otherwise? Do you have robust finances and strong ties to Nigeria (job, dependent family, property) that would compel you to return there? Why are you considering a visitor visa application at all right now, when Covid is still making life very difficult for tourists and will probably continue to do so for well into 2021?

Answer (score 10):

To apply anew...you just *apply*, as though it were the first time.

In making the application you'll be asked if you've ever previously been refused a UK visa. You should answer truthfully. UKVI will know about your previous application and refusal and ban: if you don't reveal them in the new application, UKVI will have you (again) for lying on the application; you'll be denied (again), and, perhaps, banned permanently. You should reveal your previous history, and understand that whatever your passport "agent" did in the past is your own responsibility because you were the applicant. That is, you cannot avoid responsibility by attempting to blame the "agent."

A new application from you will be scrutinized very carefully. It is likely that your previous refusal and ban will count very heavily against you, and significantly reduce the chances that this time you will obtain a visa.

Because of your prior refusal and ban, you should consider hiring a UK solicitor (i.e., a qualified lawyer located in the UK) to prepare the application for you. Do not use a local "agent."

Hiring a solicitor in the UK will be expensive. All of us here would agree that hiring a UK solicitor will increase your chances of success. Even if you do hire a UK solicitor, however, there can be no guarantee that your new application will be successful.

Comment: It's worth stressing that if OP's new application gets refused, the next application after that will be in an even more difficult position. It's crucial that OP gets it right this time. OP, please refrain from applying just right now unless you can make a 105% bulletproof application. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216 for some context.

Comment: There have been major changes in UK immigration rules including bans.

Comment: OmoNaija, from one brother to the other I will say immediately after you apply, simply forget about the application. Your chances are slim and none and you should not get your hopes up at all. If you have plans to visit other countries, proceed. One mitigating factor may be your age at the time, being supposedly a minor but still.