# UKVI agreed to reconsider but after 3 months refused again. Now what

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-ties, proof-of-employment

Please see attached my letter for refusal after UKVI agreed to reconsider my application. They've now com up with different refusal reasons from their first refusal.

I hope someone can help and advice me on the next step.

Thank you

REASONS FOR REFUSAL

You have applied for a visa to visit the UK.
In deciding whether you meet the requirements of [Appendix V: Visitor of the Immigration
Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor),
I have considered:

 your application and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
 your immigration history
The decision
I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the
requirements of paragraph V4 of Appendix V of the Immigration Rules because:

 I am aware that you were previously refused entry clearance because the Entry
Clearance Officer at that time was not satisfied that you met the Immigration Rules. I
have re-assessed your application and considered all of the documents you have
submitted and the information provided by you, including the information you have
provided in regards to your family ties and life in Bangladesh. However, I am not
satisfied that you have met the Immigration Rules on this occasion.
 You wish to travel to the UK for a period of 10 days to visit your partner who is
permanently resident and employed in the UK. I recognise the importance of these
visits and have taken this into account when reaching my decision. However, I must
still assess your application against the Immigration Rules for visitors and consider
your personal and economic circumstances.

 In your visa application form (VAF) you state that you are a self-employed owner of
[Redacted] Hostel, earning 279350.00 BDT annually (£2,124.57 where £1 =
128.52 BDT as per Oanda.com rate on 23/03/2023) with no additional income or
savings. You have also told us that you have caring responsibilities for your mother.
 I acknowledge that you have provided a number of documents in support of your
application including Trade Licences showing the business start date 13/02/2022,
statement of financial position as at 30/06/2021 and monthly expense summary for
October 2020 to June 2021, Business bank account from Dutch Bangla Bank Ltd
(account ending 9909), Income tax certificate, Dutch Bangla Bank joint bank statement
with your UK partner (account ending 5421); along with a letter from sponsor, stating
no objection to you accessing funds. You have provided a letter from your aunt stating
she will care for your mother in your absence, a medical letter from your mother’s
doctor.
 Your sponsor in the UK has submitted documents to include; photographs, bank
statements, invitation letter, GBR valid passport, Council tax bill and E tickets and flight itineraries showing an intention to fly to Delhi.

 In considering your self-employed status, the documents provided in support of your
application do not confirm your business is a viable concern. A trade licence is
obtained upon payment of a registration fee and it gives permission to trade and
therefore does not demonstrate that a business exists or that the business is a
financially viable one generating the income you state you receive from it. Income tax
registration for tax purposes is not evidence of business turnover or actual
income/profit earned from the stated business. The bank statements you have chosen
to provide do not confirm any personal income on a regular basis. The monthly
expense summary is not substantiated with receipts, invoices or salary paid to
employees. Whilst these are not compulsory documents it is reasonable to expect that
the owner of a business would provide documents to clarify the employment status as
declared. I am not satisfied you are employed as stated. I am not satisfied your
circumstances or intentions are as stated.
 I have taken into account that you have provided details of your sponsor’s financial and
living circumstances in the United Kingdom. However, whilst I acknowledge the documents provided, I note that your sponsor is permanently resident in the UK. From
the information provided, it does not appear that your sponsor intends to leave the UK.
Therefore, on the balance of probabilities, I am therefore satisfied that your ties to the
UK outweigh those you have in your country of residence.

 I have considered the documents and information submitted in your application and on
the balance of probabilities I am not satisfied that you have accurately presented your
circumstances or intentions in wishing to enter the United Kingdom. This means that I
am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or that you intend to
leave the United Kingdom at the end of your proposed visit. Your application is
therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) and (c) of the Immigration Rules.

NEXT STEPS
In relation to this decision, there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

Comment: Please do also review [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) as that seems to have been one of the main concerns.

Comment: As I read it, you've submitted bank statements from a business, but no additional business accounts to help the officer understand the financial state of the business, and no proof of a regular income to you from either the business or elsewhere.  Whatever you do next, however, you should also read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99216/12065) and its answers, because you're perilously close to getting into serial refusals territory.  Your next application, in my opinion, should be made with UK-based professional legal assistance, or you risk never getting a visa.

Comment: There is no ‘what next’. UKVI has concluded thar your ties to Bangladesh are weaker than your ‘pull’ to your partner in the UK. You told them you have caring responsibilities for your mother, but there’s another family member able to cover for you. You’ve been self-employed as a hostel owner for just over a year but haven’t separated your personal income from that of the business and can leave the business to take a trip. UKVI thinks the risk that you will stay in the UK illegally is greater than the likelihood that you will leave at the end of your visit.

Comment: Hello @MadHatter thank you for your comments. I supplied my business bank account for 6 months and my personal bank statement for six, both statements showed my monthly withdrawal from my business account into my personal account.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, but the officer felt otherwise: "*The bank statements you have chosen to provide do not confirm any personal income on a regular basis*".  At any rate, we can't continue this discussion here, as the question has been closed.  I strongly recommend that you read all the linked answers, and when you think your circumstances have changed in such a way as to address the concerns, get professional help in your next application.

Comment: I will add to MadHatter's comment that "professional help" does **not**  mean a local "visa agent" but **does** mean a fully-licensed UK solicitor or UK-licensed immigration advisor.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I completely agree, and made that point in my first comment, *supra* - but reiterating it is no bad idea!