# Will there be any problem with my dad financing my planned U.S. trip when I intend to stay at least 3 months?

Tags: visas, usa, applications

I'm 23 years old and got my Bachelor degree last year. I want take a break and visit U.S. and want to stay 3 months or more, but my dad is financing my trip because I don't work. Is there a problem that I want to stay that long and I'm not financing it myself?

Comment: In order to be approved for the visa, you must demonstrate that you have a reason to leave the US at the end of your stay. What reason do you have to leave the US and return to your country?

Comment: Reason to leave is as important as finances. You have to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent.

Comment: Use the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page to search for "US presumption of immimgrant intent" for more info. The discussion on this page: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80630/ive-received-a-refusal-for-a-us-visa-twice-under-214b-how-to-make-sure-i-won/81233#81233 will help you get oriented to the challenge.

Comment: 23, no job, probably no spouse, you're from a country that needs a visa.  You look like someone who will overstay and work under the table.  I would be surprised if you get a visa.

Comment: Can you clarify your citizenship?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Yes, I do need a visa because I'm from Kosovo. The thing is I'm not planning to immigrate because if I would, I probably immigrate illegally somehow, but I always wanted to visit U.S. so that's why I want to stay that long. I know that the system works different but I have my family here and I've built all my life here so why would I let everything and stay in U.S.

Answer (score 3):

- They want clarity where the money comes from. A parent funding a 23-year-old is **normal**, so that is no problem if your father can afford it.
- They want confidence that you will leave again. That will be difficult for a 23-year-old who can spend several months on vacation -- that is, someone who has no job or studies lined up soon.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That's why I asked because I know it sounds that I want to overstay there but the thing is I have my family and everything here, so I just want to stay that much to explore as much as I can because always wanted to visit U.S..